# Ajax Update All components with JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf

Is there a way to update all components or do I have to manually select each id? I have an ajax html5 detection script and dont want have to update every component via the id.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the ID of the common parent component.

```xml
<h:panelGroup id="someParent">
    <h:someComponentToUpdate ... />
    ...
    <h:someComponentToUpdate ... />
    ...
    <h:someComponentToUpdate ... />
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
...
<f:ajax render="someParent" />
```

Or use `@all` to refresh the entire page.

```xml
<f:ajax render="@all" />
```

Comment: That does affect the back button of the browser. Is there a way to render all components without setting the browser history?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to invoke an update base on an event, I would recommend you use PrimeFaces. Check out their showcase at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf. Below show how to use update components when a button is click

```
<p:commandButton value="Test" update="container" actionListener="#{myBean.process}"/>
```

Then have a wrapper container wrap around all components that you want to update like BalusC shows above.

```
<h:panelGroup id="container">
     ...
     // All components you want to update here. 
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Just a small thing... isn´t it better to add the layout="block" to render a div? otherwiste h:panelGroup will render a span and if you have divs inside this span it results in invalid html.